# I am creating an android app and the buttons are not lining up where I put them in the designer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to make my first Android App, one that allows me to increase or decrease a number displayed.  My issue is when I look at the [designer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqzYZ.jpg) of the app in Android Studio it looks fine, however, when I run the app on an [emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EWK4.jpg), the buttons are all at the top left of the screen.  My project supports down to Android 4.0.  It is probably something really simple but with this being my first app I really don't know where to begin.  Below is the XML code of my project.  Thanks for any help/advice in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tyler.mtglifecounter.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lifeTotal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="20"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/plusOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+ 1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="82dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="230dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/minusOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="- 1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="213dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="230dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/plusFive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+ 5"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="82dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="330dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/minusfive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="- 5"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="213dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="330dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="429dp" />
```

Comment: add pictures of your desired output if you can ...

Comment: Ok, I changed the link to "Designer View" link and it should be correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo tmoran. `ConstraintLayout` has only recently become the default layout for `Android Studio` and it's quite difficult without understanding how the underlying architecture works.

The `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` and `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY` values only apply positioning in the editor, I'm not sure why these exist because they used to confuse me as well. This is why it looks correct in the `Design View` but not on the device.

What you want to do to align the buttons is use constraints, similar to have you have aligned the `TextView` using:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

What this does is centres the `TextView` in the middle of the screen and then the line:

`app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184"`

gives the button a vertical bias of 0.184. 0.5 would be directly in the middle so this is moving it (0.5 - 0.184 = ) 31.6% up the page.

So, in order to do what you want you would *first* constrain the bottom `Button` to parent using:

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

(what this does is constrains the bottom of the `Button` to the bottom of the page) you would then want to give it a margin to set it that much off the bottom:

`android:layout_marginBottom=16dp`

And then to centre it horizontally you would add:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

You can do the above without typing the code, you would want to click on the circular edges of the button and then drag them to the relevant place in the layout so they click in place. **You don't want to just click and drag the button** as this will cause only the `Design View` to change.

To get the next two sets of buttons in the correct place is more complicated. Have a look at [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains). As a previous answer had said, `ConstraintLayout` is quite advanced and `RelativeLayout` is easier, however I think that it will pay dividends if you jump in at the deep end and figure out how to use `Chains` as this will make it easier in the future.

You will want to first constrain the second last row of buttons to the bottom button and then using the same idea constrain the first row of buttons to the second row.

Comment: That worked for me and is more consistent.  I was only able to figure out the Chains through the user interface and not programatically.  Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. You deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        orientation="vertical"
        gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.tyler.mtglifecounter.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lifeTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184" />
        <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
orientation="horizontal"
gravity="center">
<Button
            android:id="@+id/plusOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+ 1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="82dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="230dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minusOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="- 1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="213dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="230dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
orientation="horizontal"
gravity="center">       
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/plusFive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+ 5"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="82dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="330dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minusfive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="- 5"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="213dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="330dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="429dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at my issue.  I made the changes to the xml code where I could see you made changes and now everything is lined up down the center where I want it to have the buttons in more of a grid pattern like shown in the designer view.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This method has worked for what I am wanting to do, I just have to mess around with the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are the `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` and `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY` attributes added by the editor, they have no real effect in the compiled application. Remove those and try to place the elements using text view (guided by the xml preview, not the design view).

If you're just starting with Android I would suggest you experiment with more simple layouts, like `RelativeLayout`